# Reverse string with exclusion rules

Tags: swift, string, reverse

I try to reverse sring and seems like i have some succes in this case:

```
let sampleSentence = "I like to learn Swift"

    func reverseWordsInSentence(sentence: String) -> String {
    var sentence = sentence
    sentence.enumerateSubstrings(in: sentence.startIndex..., options: .byWords) { _, range, _, _ in
        sentence.replaceSubrange(range, with: sentence[range].reversed())
    }
    return sentence
}
```

But I'm trying to go further and make sure that the reverse of the line does not affect the numbers
for example:

```
let sampleSentence = "Test 1, I like to learn Swift 24/7"
```

now i have result:

```
print(reverseWordsInSentence(sentence: sampleSentence)) // 1tseT, I ekil ot nrael tfiwS 42/7
```

my goal is to achieve results:

```
print(reverseWordsInSentence(sentence: sampleSentence)) // tseT1, I ekil ot nrael tfiwS 24/7
```

I will be glad to any hints!

Comment: you can simply skip the `reverse` algorithm when it is not character.

Comment: You'll need a more precise definition for your algorithm than "does not affect the numbers." For example, what should the result be when numbers and letters mix? `I like to learn Swift 24hours/7days!` Should `24hours/7days` be `24hours/7days`, `24sruoh/7syad`, `syad7/hours24`, `24/sruoh7days` or something else? And where should the `!` go?

Comment: @RobNapier you're right. if i have number ald lettrs mix like: I like to learn Swift 24hours/7days! should be 24sruoh/7syad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a check inside the closure and just return if the substring contains all numbers

```
guard let string = string, !string.allSatisfy(\.isNumber) else  {
    return
}
```

Full code

```
func reverseWordsInSentence(sentence: String) -> String {
   var sentence = sentence
   sentence.enumerateSubstrings(in: sentence.startIndex..., options: .byWords) { string, range, _, _ in

       guard let string = string, !string.allSatisfy(\.isNumber) else  {
           return
       }
       sentence.replaceSubrange(range, with: sentence[range].reversed())
   }
   return sentence
}
```